# How can I improve the speed of solution of Set Covering problem with MiniZinc?

Tags: minizinc

Recently I trying to solve a Set Covering Problem Instances proposed by [Balas, E., & Ho, A. (1980)] with MiniZinc.

I tried two ways or models for solving SCP41 instance:

Models

(1). ILP model

https://github.com/affernan/minizinctest/blob/master/scp_mzinc_lp.mzn

(2). ILP model with code, forall, array, etc.. I'm not sure if models (1)==(2) https://github.com/affernan/minizinctest/blob/master/scp_mzinc_code.mzn

For each run of each model on SCP41, MiniZinc never finish iterating or reaching the optimum.  I understand that the instances and the problem are very combinatorial, but in what way can the models be improved?

regards!

Comment: Have you seen [this nice example](http://www.hakank.org/minizinc/set_covering4b.mzn) by [@hakank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/195636/hakank)?

Comment: @PatrickTrentin I used the same code example and modified it, after seeing that the model (1) did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both these models are solved by MiniZinc's `mip` solver within seconds (4.2s and 2.4s respectively on my machine). What solver did you try?

Later: Here's a slightly faster version: http://www.hakank.org/minizinc/scp41.mzn (0.6s using the mip/cbc solver).

Comment: @hakannk I was testing with MiniZinc Solver Configuration [Gecode] and a model of its github, and I was not finished. Now I tried OSICBC and got good results with both models. What difference can the type of Solver configuration selected? speed, heuristic, domain set variable, branching?

Comment: @user1813375 It's not uncommon that one have to try different solvers - e.g. CP solvers, MIP solvers, and SAT solvers - as well as solver configurations - e.g. different search heuristics such as variable and variables strategies - to be able to solve effectively a certain problem, especially when the instances get larger.  It might help to add symmetry breaking constraints etc. One have to try different things, and sometimes one have to rewrite a model completely. It's an engineering art...

Comment: @hakannk I believe that variable strategies is a key element. I know that the SAT-Solver as Z3 already incorporate optimization module, how competitive can Z3 be with respect to MiniZinc?

Comment: z3 is a solver - as well as a constraint language - and MiniZinc is a constraint language, not a solver (though the distribution do include a couple of solvers) so they are not really comparable. What you can compare are the different FlatZinc solvers such as Gecode, Chuffed, CBC etc against z3 but it all depends on the specific problem.  z3 support things that's not in the MiniZinc language. 

Some time ago, I wrote some z3/python models (see http://hakank.org/z3/ ), but was not impressed by the speed of z3;  but perhaps I didn't use z3 the proper way.

Comment: @user1813375 Oh, and it's "hakank", not "hakannk". :-)

Comment: ok, I understand better now. I have in mind some research ideas about collaborative strategies that may arise between SAT solvers, mainly with Z3. I appreciate your explanations, thank you!